# Using XPATH to select two different attributes - from different nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

So I am trying (with a pre-XPATH 2.0 environment) to select two attributes from the same search result ... my data looks like (this is an extract of course)

```
      <ATHLETES>
        <ATHLETE athleteid="1010" lastname="Doe" firstname="John" gender="M" key="12345">
          <RESULTS>
            <RESULT resultid="1673" time="00:00:31.00" status=""/>
```

Given the resultid, I want to locate the time, and the key, which is in the higher node.

I can extract the resultid and time with
//ATHLETES/ATHLETE/RESULTS/RESULT[@resultid='1673']/@*[name() ='time' or name() ='resultid']";
but how to I get to the attribute called "key" in the parent's parent node?

Monathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a very clean (non-repetitive) way to do this in XPath 1.0, but you can use the union operator (`|`) to select both attributes in a single query:

```
//ATHLETES/ATHLETE[RESULTS/RESULT/@resultid = '1673']/@key |    
//ATHLETES/ATHLETE/RESULTS/RESULT[@resultid = '1673']/@time
```